# URL renaming issue

Tags: url-rewriting, urls

I am a non programmer using a wordpress site (riyachting.com)  I just discoverd that sending folks to my page with a URL that inlcudes  some other stuff in it gets stripped out so only the URL of the page remains.... i guess it's getting renamed.

We want to use this link to launch a lightbox with content...

http://www.riyachting.com#liteboxlive:station-box::href:http%3A%2F%2Fwww.marinemotion.com%2Fstations%2Friyachting%2Friy_sponsors%2Fblue-water-yachts-adds-jeanneau::referrer:http%3A%2F%2Fwww.riyachting.com

Is there a way to  turn off that function so the site will accept our links.. we plan to do this all the time.

Comment: Sounds like a browser issue.  When I click your link the light box is open.

Comment: I can second that, it works.

Answer (score 3):

When I go to `www.riyachting.com`, I get redirected to `riyachting.com`. [Some browsers remove the fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286402/url-fragment-and-302-redirects) (part after the `#`) of the URL in this redirect.

Chrome keeps the original fragment and the lightbox works. Safari removes it and the lightbox doesn't work. So either use the final URL in your link, or use something else than URL fragments to load the lightbox.